# Access router from ADSL modem

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, modem

I have the following set-up:

- Linksys WAG320N modem-router connected to the internet via RJ11
- Gateway IP for WAG320N is `10.0.1.1`, subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`
- Static IPv4 address for my EA6500 router is `10.0.1.100`

This modem is connected to my EA6500 router:

- Linksys EA6500 connected to WAG320N on port 1
- Gateway IP for EA6500 is `10.0.2.1`, subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`
- EA6500 is set to auto-config DHCP mode under internet settings

I can connect to all my devices when I am connected to the EA6500, including the ones connected to the modem (WAG320N). But I cannot connect to EA6500's GUI or any devices connected to it when I try accessing them via the WAG320N.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is by design you are trying to access an entirely different network that WAG320N isn't aware of.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work? Would a Bridged Mode on my EA6500 help?

Comment: I managed to get full LAN access both ways, after reading and following this: http://www.ezlan.net/router_AP.html . But I cannot connect to the internet afterwards. Any alternatives?